# How to make child object follow a parent armature?

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to do a bit of character modelling for my little game and after following a number of tutorials I reached a point where I could start animating my character, if not this strange problem. 
because in the future I'd like to add hats and change haircuts, I have created hair as a separate object. This object has child constraint with the target being the bone controlling the head:

[image: Contstraint setup]

This generally works, with the exception of when I rotate the main character along Z axis, where the hair goes in opposite direction. Rotation along X and Y axes works just fine.

Can you possibly help me to solve it?

One additional piece of information, that might be relevant: when I added the constraint to the hair object, it moved down and rotated 180d along Z. I had to turn it and manually moved back to the top of the head.

I'm using blender 2.81.

kind regards!

Tom

Comment: Try to add the head bone as parent of the hair in the Object Properties (little orange square icon)>>Relation

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Omg, thank you so much FFeller!
Searched this for days, tried everything!